# Need to find difference between times (saved as strings)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I’m attempting to calculate the duration that fishermen spend at a single location. However The data given to me is a little funky and I was able to get the two times extracted from a column that included both date and time (where time_fix = start time and end_time = last time collected at a point for an individual fisher). I want to simply subtract these numbers and I’m unable to use the age() function as the values are saved as strings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, it is still not working for me.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZZ8d.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZZ8d.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Add a new field with a type of `String`, name it `time_diff` or any name you like. Then, try the following formula, and you should get the desired output:

```
 minute(to_time("end_time") - to_time( "time_fix"))
```

In the following example, I used `start_time` instead of `time_fix`, and the output is as expected:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try with `to_time("end_time",'H:mm')`